Is this a valid way of showing that $x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$?
We apply the Eisenstein criteria for an integral domain $R$, i.e. if $p=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n\in R[x]$, then if there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ such that $a_i\in \mathfrak p$ for $i\neq n$, $a_n\notin \mathfrak p$, and $a_0\not \mathfrak p^2$ we have that $p$ is irreducible.
Take $R=\mathbb C[x,y]$, then $p=a_0+a_2z^2$, with $a_2=1$, and $a_0=x^2+y^2-1$. Clearly $x^2+y^2-1\in \langle x^2+y^2-1 \rangle$, but not in $\langle x^2+y^2-1 \rangle^2$, so if we can show that $\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle$ is prime then we are done.
We apply Eisenstein's criterion again, with $r=\mathbb C[x]$, then $a_0=x^2-1$, and $a_2=y^2$. We take $\mathfrak p=\langle x+1\rangle$, then $x^2+1\in \langle x+1\rangle$, as $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ but $x^2+1\notin \langle x+1\rangle ^2$, as otherwise $x+1$ divides $x^2+1$ twice which can't be true. It follows that $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible, so $\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle$ is prime, so the original polynomial $q$ is irreducible.
I have just learned of the generalization of Eisenstein's criterion outside of polynomials over the integers, so I wanted to try and apply it to a more complicated multivariate case. Since I am new to this theorem, I am unsure if I actually applied this correctly, in particular I see no reason why I can't apply Eisenstein's criterion twice, but I am mildly suspicious of this step. Any feed back would be appreciated.
Edit:
I think this actually extends to a very nice proof that $q=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]$, when $n\geq 2$. Indeed, we proved the base case that $x_1^2+x_2^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[x_1,x_2]$, now suppose the $n-1$th case, that $x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2-1$ is prime in $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}]=R$. We can write $q$ as a polynomial in $R[x_n]$ via $a_0+x_n^2$. Then the prime $\langle x_1^2x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2-1 \rangle$ satisfies the Eisenstein criterion, so $q$ is irreducible.

You have made some typos where $x^2+1$ should be $x^2-1$, but otherwise the proof is almost fine. The proof should also mention that (and this is maybe part of your confusion?) $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\bigl[z\bigr]$, and that this isomorphism maps $x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ to $z^2+(x^2+y^2-1)$. Similarly for the 2nd reduction.
You can also adapt the proof easily to show by induction that $x_1^2+\cdots + x_n^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. In your proof, you did (a special case of) the induction step twice. This way, you just have to do it once (in a general setting, but not more complicated at all). EDIT: just saw your edit, nice one (apart from the typo in the end).
